# Negative Numbers Give Error NaN in Javascript

Tags: javascript, math, negative-number

I am trying to write a code about changing numbers to its cube root but whenever i enter a negative number, i receive NaN error.

Tried to use string to number function called Number

```
let number = prompt("Enter a number");
if (number > 0 || number < 0){
    let x = number**(1/3);
    alert(x);
}
else if (number == 0){
    alert(number);
}
else{
    alert("Error");
}
```

I enter -8 for example, i expect it will give me -2 as result but i receive NaN

Answer (score 0):

This is because cube-root of a negative number has complex numbers as solutions along with a negative real number, to get the negative real number you have to write a simple logic:

```js
function cubeRoot(number){
   const isNegative =  number < 0;
   const cubeRoot =  Math.pow(Math.abs(number), 1/3);
   return isNegative ? -cubeRoot : cubeRoot;
 }
 console.log(cubeRoot(-8));
 console.log(cubeRoot(0));
 console.log(cubeRoot(8));
```

There is a library available to do this: [math.js](https://mathjs.org/docs/getting_started.html)

```js
console.log(math.cbrt(-8));
console.log(math.cbrt(0));
console.log(math.cbrt(8));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjs/6.2.1/math.js"></script>
```

Comment: "cube-root of a negative number is not real" - why? `cbrt(-8) = -2`

Comment: @georg I re-phrased the answer, I hope I got it right. My math skills are rusty.

Comment: The actual problem is that `** 1/3` is not a cube root, because `1/3` is not the mathematical one-third, but rather some floating point approximation of it (explained very nicely in the dupe).